# How to expit transfration to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Here's my dataset

```
Id      B       C      
1       0      -1
2       2      -2
```

here's the expit transformation `(exp(x)/(1+exp(x)))`

```
Id     B               C      
1      0.5         0.269
2      0.881       0.119
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use vectorization:

```
import numpy as np

df.iloc[:, 1:] = np.exp(df.iloc[:, 1:])/(1+np.exp(df.iloc[:, 1:]))
print(df)

# Output:
   Id         B         C
0   1  0.500000  0.268941
1   2  0.880797  0.119203
```

You can also define your columns explicitly:

```
cols = ['B', 'C']
df[cols] = np.exp(df[cols])/(1+np.exp(df[cols]))
```

Comment: I show some ways to simplify the problem a bit in my answer, which may improve performance. But the general idea is the same~

Answer (score 2):

As you said, this transformation is sometimes called an Expit, and `SciPy` has a specific function for calculating it.

```
from scipy.special import expit

cols = ['B', 'C']
df[cols] = expit(df[cols])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Id         B         C
0   1  0.500000  0.268941
1   2  0.880797  0.119203
```

---

Using `numpy` we can still simplify the equation a bit:

```
df[cols] = 1/(1+np.exp(-df[cols]))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Id         B         C
0   1  0.500000  0.268941
1   2  0.880797  0.119203
```

Answer (score 1):

You could apply the `apply` function as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data={"B": [0,2], "C": [-1,-2]})
#    B  C
# 0  0 -1
# 1  2 -2

df.apply(lambda x: np.exp(x)/(1+np.exp(x)))
#           B         C
# 0  0.500000  0.268941
# 1  0.880797  0.119203
```